# sql query to get data by date and time

Tags: java, date, time, ucanaccess

I want to get the rows where date and time are greater then given date. Here is my table:

```
EvDate      EvTime      ClBdg   Name    Event
18.01.2015  10:55:01    001     Jane    enter
18.01.2015  19:31:21    003     Brad    exit
19.01.2015  13:31:21    002     Lucy    exit
```

Given `date` is `18.01.2015`, `time` is `17:00:00`. Desired values are:

```
EvDate      EvTime      ClBdg   Name    Event
18.01.2015  19:31:21    003     Brad    exit
19.01.2015  13:31:21    002     Lucy    exit
```

Can anyone helps me?

Edit:
To be more clear I edited my post. Here is the java code to execute the query:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdfTime=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdfDate=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");  
private long givenTimeStamp = 1421600400L;
public static Date givenDate = new Date(givenTimeStamp);

Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");  
String DATABASE = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+CONF.getString("db.location")+";jackcessOpener=uz.lexus.access.crypto.MyCryptoProvider";  
connection= DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE, null, null);  

List<Event> events=new ArrayList<Event>();  
String selectEvents = "select EvDate,EvTime,ClBdg,Event from Evntlog_tbl where  Event in ('enter','exit') and not ClBdg=0 and EvDate >= ? and EvTime > ?  order by EvDate desc, EvTime desc";
PreparedStatement prstm= connection.prepareStatement(selectEvent);  
java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(sdfDate.parse(sdfDate.format()).getTime(givenDate));  
java.sql.Time time=new Time(sdfTime.parse(sdfTime.format(givenDate)).getTime());  

prstm.setDate(1,date);  
prstm.setTime(2,time); 

ResultSet rs = prstm.executeQuery();
```

> Now the question is: Is the query in the selectEvent correct?

Comment: which database you are using answer depends on it

Comment: What flavor of SQL (or what **concrete** database) are you using? Those are all slightly different in how they deal with these things! Please add a relevant tag (like `oracle`, `postgresql`, `mysql`, `db2`, `sql-server` etc. to your question!)

Comment: what is the datatype of `EvDate` & `EvTime`

Comment: EvDate is type of Date, EvTime is Time

Comment: Did you tried anything ? If not then read about `WHERE` clause in sql server here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx

Comment: I have tried "SELECT * FROM EvntLog_tbl WHERE EvDate >= '18.01.2015' AND EvTime > '17:00:00';" .  But it gives wrong rows

Comment: The problem is the logic, not the types. As it is, the query asks for future events that occur only after `17:00`, where it should ask either for all events after the parameters date, or those that occur after `17:00` on the same date

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'v edited the post, can you suggest anything now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this ,
As you have two different columns for `Evdate` and `EvTime`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE EvDate >'18.01.2015'  OR (EvDate = '18.01.2015' AND EvTime > '17:00:00'
```

**Update**-

attaching a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f326/1/0) , will be helpful .

Comment: @LeXuS *this* is probably the optimal query (assuming a cast to datetime is added). It ensures any underlying indexes will be used by the query optimizer. Applying functions to columns prevents the optimizer from using indexes, although it's usually smart enough to handle some date operations

Comment: @LeXuS if you have created index on any one of these both field or on field then i would like to suggest you to use this query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can I write it in java

Comment: @Nimesh Thanks for your sugession, but to write the query in this condition would be more complicated

Comment: @LeXuS then u should create a view with the combined field `(EvDate + EvTime) As EvDateTime` and try to retrieve the records from that view. you can also create index on it.

Comment: @LeXuS more complicated than what? The point is to get both the correct results and good performance. You can create an indexed view with a single datetime column as Nimesh suggests, or add a calculated column with an index on it but you can argue that this is *more* complex.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I said so because I'm new in sql queries, so in programming

Comment: @varsha I've tried like this:  

  `selectEvents = "select EvDate,EvTime,ClBdg,Event from Evntlog_tbl where  Event in ('enter','exit') and not ClBdg=0 and (EvDate = ? OR (EvDate > ? and EvTime > ?))  order by EvDate desc, EvTime desc";`

Comment: @LeXuS I could only help u in query as java is not my domain. happy that it worked for you . happy coding . :)

Comment: @LeXuS take a look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f326/1/0). Varsha you can add this example in your answer as a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 
WHERE EvDate + EvTime > '2015-01-18T17:00:00'
```

Instead you could consider creating a PERSISTED computed column that adds date and time. Persisted computed columns will allow index

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD cEVdatetime AS EvDate + EvTime PERSISTED
```

Comment: I wonder, is the query optimizer smart enough to use any indexes on `EvDate` and `EvTime` or is the addition going to force an index scan?

Comment: If any index is created on any field then it will be removed and the performance may get down.

Comment: @Nimesh not so , which is why I ask. SQL Server's optimizer is usually able to convert `DATEADD` or addition operations to range seeks.

Answer (score 0):

This might hepls you

```
declare @t table(a date,b time)
insert into  @t values (getdate(),'7:00:00 AM')

select * from @t
where a>'2015/01/19' or (a=getdate() and a>'6:00:00 AM')
```

Answer (score 0):

i am assume that EvDate Datatype is Date and EvTime Datatype is Time .
Try This ....

select 
      * from yourtablename
where  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),EvDate ,112)>=20150118 AND EvTime >='17:00:00'

Comment: The typical advice is to convert strings to proper dates and times, not the other way around. Moreover, this solves nothing. The problem isn't the (non-existent) format of the `datetime` type, it's checking `EvTime` even for future dates